# warp string url into html link tag

Tags: php, mysql

so i trying to replace url(like www.google.com) into html link tag like this

```
return preg_replace('"\b(www.\S+)"', '<a href="$1" style="color:white;">$1</a>', $url);
```

this is modified preg_replace from somewhere else and i still don't fully understand how it works....

so if i using this i will get

```
<a href"www.google.com" style="color:white;">www.google.com</a>
```

and this mean it will look for www.google.com in my web directory and not opening www.google.com website

what i trying to achieve is

```
<a href"http://www.google.com" style="color:white;">google</a>
```

so how to achieve something like that? and it will be better if when i type

```
http://www.google.com
```

then it will also replace

```
http://www.
```

too.... 
if my configuration for current is just replace www. but if i type with http:// then it will only warp from www.google.com and leaving http://

edit:
so i want a flexibel one, so if i type www.google.com or http://www.google.com it will catch it and turn it into link tag....
and also if i type like https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124/ it will only show like

```
<a href"https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124/" style="color:white;">stackoverflow</a>
```

2nd edit : i sorry, i forgot that say that i also want to keep other text within the link.. so it will be like i'm typing "here is a big news in www.xxxxx.com" and when i display it/ it will be "here is a big news in xxxxx" where xxxxx is gonna be clickable links... 
and i trying to do this because i'm gonna use it for my website announcement part...

can we do something like that?

update:

i have thinking about some idea, how about first we do preg_replace to catch http:// and remove it, after that we catch www. to warp it into html link tag and also catch www. and everything afer .com/.co/or .whatever and remove it all until the next space

but i don't know how to use preg_replace since i have no idea how it works

Comment: You mean `<a href=` otherwise, it won't be a valid `href`.

Comment: We need to see what you're using `$url` as. Is it "google"? Is it "www.google.com"? Other?

Comment: well i want it flexibel so if $url = www.google.com or $url = http://www.google.com it will just giving the same output as <a href="http://www.google.com >google</a>

Comment: Have a look at what I posted below. It's one way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

This is about the closest I could come up with, in order to do what you want to achieve.

There are others ways I'm sure, but you can give the following a try.

You could have the following inside a text file: (you can have 1 or more lines)

**bookmark.txt** (in the exact format shown) - You don't need to put the `http://` it's automatic.

***Sidenote:*** You can use `google.com` or `www.google.com` - Only the word `Google` will appear as the link, but the full `href` will appear in the HTML source and be a valid URL.

```
Google google.com
Yahoo yahoo.com
stackoverflow stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124
```

Then use the following PHP:

```
<?php 
$file = "bookmark.txt";
$lines = file($file);
foreach($lines as $line)
{
    $piece=explode(" ",$line);
    $link=trim($piece[1]);
    $text=trim($piece[0]);
    echo '<a href="http://'.$link.'">'.$text.'</a><br>';
}
```

***Notes:*** The `" "` in `$piece=explode(" ",$line);` represents a space being the seperator.

You can change it to `$piece=explode("|",$line);` then changing the text file to:

```
Google|google.com
Yahoo|yahoo.com
stackoverflow|stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124
```

should you decide to use something like `Google Search`

I.e.:

```
Google Search|google.com
Yahoo|yahoo.com
stackoverflow link|stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124
```

---

***You can also try:***

```
$content = "http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124";
$content = preg_replace('$(https?://[a-z0-9_./?=&#-]+)(?![^<>]*>)$i', ' <a href="$1" target="_blank">StackOverflow</a> ', $content." ");

echo $content;
```

---

But at this point and reading your question over and over including your edit, I am not entirely sure that is what you want, and stands at being very broad and beyond the scope of my knowledge with PHP.

Comment: well thank you for your effort.... i tried the second method and it only work with http:// and https:// and it can't catch the link if i start with www. and also the link tags warp the predefine text which is stackoverflow, how to change according to the text that being catch... and for the first one i'm not trying it yet but from what i see it looks like its only focus on the text that want to change into link.... well it's my fault also, i forgot to explain that i not only giving link input but also along with other text...

Comment: @PUCUK You're welcome. I wasn't entirely sure that it would have solved your problem. I tried, *cheers*

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
 $text = ' This is a text with the link of google.com. And another phrase with google.com url.';
 echo str_replace('google.com','<a href="http://google.com" target=_blank>google</a>',$text);
```

Comment: well www.google.com is only example... i want it to catch any url not only www.google.com

Answer (score 0):

you were always right but just a simple typing mistake was done

```
<a href"http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124/" style="color:white;">stackoverflow</a>
```

You missed the '=' equal sign after href. please try this instead

```
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26154124/" style="color:white;">stackoverflow</a>
```

hope it helps...

Comment: oh sorry it just typo in this question ahahhaa mostly i use autocomplete so i almost never type "=" or even i just type "h" and everything come like "href=" ahahhaah :D